# Storing Physical Path on database instead of virtual one

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

My problem I believe is simple, but I am struggling with it.
When I upload image files, it works fine, but the path on database is physical one, like **C://user/pictures/blabla....** .
I would like to change it to **virtual path (~/...)**. 
The images are displyed when I change manually the database path to virtual one.
Thanks in advance for any help.
Here are my codes:

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult Create(DriverReg model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var phisicalPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/uploads/"), fileName);
                    file.SaveAs(phisicalPath);
                    DriverReg newRecord = new DriverReg();
                    newRecord.FullName = model.FullName;
                    newRecord.Address = model.Address;
                    newRecord.Postcode = model.Postcode;
                    newRecord.Contact = model.Contact;
                    newRecord.Email = model.Email;
                    newRecord.County = model.County;
                    newRecord.File = phisicalPath;
                    newRecord.Date = DateTime.Now;

                    db.DriverRegs.Add(newRecord);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

**CREATE VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <input type="file" class="file-input" name="file" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**DETAILS VIEW**

```
 <dt>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.File)
            </dt>

            <dd>
                @Html.Image(@Model.File, "image")
            </dd>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the virtual path before you call Server.MapPath on it, then use that in your DB record.

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var combinedVirtualPath = Path.Combine("~/Content/uploads", fileName);
var phisicalPath = Server.MapPath(combinedVirtualPath);
file.SaveAs(phisicalPath);
DriverReg newRecord = new DriverReg();
newRecord.FullName = model.FullName;
newRecord.Address = model.Address;
newRecord.Postcode = model.Postcode;
newRecord.Contact = model.Contact;
newRecord.Email = model.Email;
newRecord.County = model.County;
newRecord.File = combinedVirtualPath;
newRecord.Date = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I've tried your code and didn't work, it cuases an error **file is a physical path, but a virtual path was expected**

Comment: Thanks guys, the update from Ashley was perfect. You saved my day

Answer (score 0):

How about just assigning the virtual path to a variable?

```
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
var destination = $"~/Content/uploads/{fileName}";
var physicalPath = Server.MapPath(destination);
file.SaveAs(physicalPath);
```

Then just store the contents of the ***destination*** variable

Comment: Thanks DVK, I've tried your answer, but remains physical path on db, any other sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

```
var phisicalPath = Path.Combine(("~/Content/uploads/"), fileName);
```

or

```
string filePath = @"~/Content/uploads/"
var phisicalPath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
```